# problems with request and cheerio in dialogflow

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

What I'm trying to do is to be able to use request-promise-native and cheerio in my dialogflow webhook to scrape some articles from a website, I've tried several ways but never been able to work it out.

My last attempt was doing as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422410/use-async-functions-in-dialogflow-webhook) post, but i could not make it work.

If you want to have a look at my code, here it is the code i wrote, with a bit of explanation: https://github.com/Vaelthur/webscraping-with-dialogflow-incomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the function registered to the `scrpwb` intent.

You are calling `prova_promise`, which returns a Promise (which is correct!), but does not itself return a Promise. So the function returns nothing, which is handled immediately by the handler rather than waiting for the Promise to complete.

The solution is simple - make sure it returns a Promise which you can do with something like

```
  return prova_promise().then((message) => {
```

and the rest being exactly the same.